# Selenium arsparse for headless chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, arguments, argparse, headless-browser

So I have built a testing framework and I am able to run it Headless in the normal fashion.

```
    self.chrome_options = Options()
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options,
                                   service=Service(
                                       ChromeDriverManager().install())
                                   )
```

What I am looking for, as I built this for my colleagues and they don't want to have to go in and comment out the line `self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` every time they don't want the tests to run headless, is an **argsparse** so that they can run something like test_file.py --headless.

So far I have this

```
args = self.args_cmds()
    if args['--headless:'] == 'True':
        self.chrome_options.headless = True
    else:
        self.chrome_options.headless = False

    self.chrome_options = Options()
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1480')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options,
                                   service=Service(
                                       ChromeDriverManager().install())
                                   )

    self.pixel = 4.9667

def args_cmds(self):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--headless:', help='Specifies if you want a window to open or not.')
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args
```

The function `def args_cmd(self):` is called under the `if __name__ == "__main__":` section. Yet when I run this I get the error **error: argument --headless:: expected one argument**

If anyone has any ideas that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify that `--headless` argument is a boolean argument and has default value `True`:

```
def args_cmds(self):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--headless:', action='store_true', help='Specifies if you want a window to open or not.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

and then use `args` as

```
args = self.args_cmds()
if args.headless: 
    self.chrome_options.headless = True
else:
    self.chrome_options.headless = False
```

You can also try to execute your script as

```
script.py --headless 'True'
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error: argument --headless:: expected one argument, unfortunately.

Comment: @Halfbrowse ok.. try `parser.add_argument('--headless:', action='store_true', help='Specifies if you want a window to open or not.')`

Comment: So I did as you said and now the error is as follows : in __init__ if args['--headless:']:
KeyError: '--headless:'

Comment: @Halfbrowse try `args = parser.parse_args()` and then `if args.headless: self.chrome_options.headless = True`